# php mkdir windows relative path

Tags: php, windows, path, relative-path, mkdir

I want to create a directory on windows from a PHP script.

My script is in the `www/Test` directory of Apache and I want to create a folder (fold1) inside `www/downloads` directory.

Inside the script, I'm using:

```
$dirName = "../downloads/fold1";   
mkdir("{$dirName}");
```

If I use the full path of dirName like `C:\Apache\www\downloads\fold1`, it works fine.

But I want to use a relative path since this code will be sent to the client.

Comment: does it show any error messages?

Comment: It does not create the folder, does not show any errors.

Comment: well you have to turn error messages on. You should read an error message before asking any question. 
using realpath() for debugging purposes also helps

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` is the quick way to bring errors on the screen.

Comment: Or at least `get_error_last()` or `$php_errormsg`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would guess your current directory is different from your files folder, so you have to use a trick:

```
mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . "/" . $relative_path);
```

`dirname(__FILE___)` returns the absolute path of your current php file. With this you can build an absolut path.

Comment: With php 5.3 you can even use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: this absolute path is no better than relative one.

Comment: and guessing is not the thing a programmer should ever rely on.

Comment: because it's still relative from the current script location.

Comment: No? By prefixing it with the absolute path of the script you get an absolute path. Yes it contains relative elements by using .. and so on, but I don't see any problems with that when his app gets deployed to a customer.